# How to get id on a successful model.save()?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Have checked some backbone.js tutorials and can't 
understand how to get model id from the server within 
the model saving process. I have a model:

```
var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: '',
        releaseDate: ''
    },
    url: function(){
        return '/data.php';
    } 
});
```

How to implement getting the id algorithm? It seams to me, there should 
be a kind of callback function, but can't realise where to put it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Backbone's documentation on [model save](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save).

You can pass a success callback function to save, something like this:

```
var game = new Game({
    name: 'Duke Nukem 3D',
    releaseDate: '1996'
});

game.save({}, {
    success: function(model, response) {
        // get model id from response?
    }
);
```